# Integrate applications using multiple programming languages into a Java application

Tags: java, programming-languages, integration, polyglot

Is there an open source application that could integrate applications using multiple programming languages into a Java application?

Comment: Java is not an acronym, or a word to be shouted (often)

Comment: What do you mean by "applications"? Desktop apps? Web apps?

Answer (score 2):

Some options:

- Languages that can be compiled and run into the JVM, like python and javascript. But you might have a difficult time if the programs where not built from the beggining to run inside the JVM.
- JNI, java's native interface. This allows interfacing Java with native (i.e. C) languages. If your other language is not C or C++ then probably you will need to write a native interface for them too.
- API. Using web services or socket communication have the two languages communicate.
- Sharing data. Having both programs share files or databases in a common format.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you mean, but there are [several languages that could be compiled to Java byte code and run under JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages).

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface

The Java Native Interface is a programming framework that allows Java code running in a Java Virtual Machine to call and to be called by native applications (programs specific to a hardware and operating system platform) and libraries written in other languages, such as C, C++ and assembly.